# File `glyphtounicode.tex' not found

Tags: bakoma

I don't know why I don't have this file.
It gives me the following error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `glyphtounicode.tex' not found.
```

I have used the `\input{glyphtounicode}`

Comment: it is part of the core pdftex distribution, in texlive it is `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftex/glyphtounicode.tex` from yourtag I assume you are using bakoma tex so you might want to check with the maintainers where it is or get a copy from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/4f771e41a6c3799e9d16e44633c7fa95dc41f1bc/texk/lcdf-typetools/lcdf-typetools-src/glyphtounicode.tex

Answer (score 0):

You can download it, then put it in your working directory. [Check it here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/4f771e41a6c3799e9d16e44633c7fa95dc41f1bc/texk/lcdf-typetools/lcdf-typetools-src/glyphtounicode.tex)